# Is there a fast way to change proxy setting?

Tags: network, applescript, system-settings

On my laptop I usually have a ssh connection open and use the remote machine as a proxy server just so that all my network traffic is over ssh. I know that it's hopeless and we're all doomed, but it makes me feel a little better.

Problem is sometimes I need to set and unset it for some reason and then I have to dig through millions of dialogs to get to here...

[image]

...so that I can uncheck that option.

Is there a faster way to do that or a way I can set up a script to turn "SOCKS Proxy" on and off? Probably something with Applescript, right?

Is there a way to do this without learning Applescript?

Comment: This method is really inefficient, btw. You are tunnelling TCP over TCP, and it slows things down a lot. Check SSHuttle for one solution, or use a vpn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up two locations - one with proxy one - one off - you are an Apple menu item away from the switch.

[image: Apple Menu]

Just select network, then edit the locations.

[image: network][image: location]

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Alfred](http://alfredapp.com), you can try a variant of [this extension](http://yjsoon.com/2011/08/shell-script-to-toggle-network-proxy-in-lion):

```
e=$(networksetup -getsocksfirewallproxy wi-fi | grep "No")

if [ -n "$e" ]; then
  echo "Turning on proxy"
  networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi on
else
  echo "Turning off proxy"
  networksetup -setsocksfirewallproxystate wi-fi off
fi
```

For more information, look up the `networksetup` command line function. (Note that you may need to change `wi-fi` above to something else -- `ethernet` for wired connections, or `airport` if you're on Snow Leopard.)